# I want to check if I send the message in Discord.py-rewrite. But, it dosent work for some reason

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def ree(ctx):
    if(ctx.message.author.name == "TheDogeKing_X#8429"):
        await ctx.send("test completed")
```

This doesn't work for some reson

Comment: Have you tried printing message.author.name to the console to check it's what you think it is?

Comment: Also if you're trying to check if the owner of the bot is the one who ran the command, there is an @is_owner decorator, alternatively you could do `if await client.is_owner(ctx.message.author):
    print("owner!")
else:
    print("not owner!")`

Comment: `author.name` will result in just `TheDogeKing_X` , use IDs instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rewrite, you do not use (pass_context) and it's ctx.author.name, not ctx.message.author.name. Also if you are using .name, you do not include a discriminator (#8429). So as far as i know, the code would be:

`@client.command()
async def ree(ctx):
    if(ctx.author.name == "TheDogeKing_X"):
        await ctx.send("test completed")`

I personally am not very experienced with checking if the member has a certain name so this still might not work, however, i did put it in correct grammar.